# Converting VS2008 to VS2010 project "cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to upgrade a Visual C++ 2008 project to a Visual C++ 2010 project. However, when I attempt to do so, I receive the following error:

`The following error has occurred during XML parsing: File: C:\Documents and Settings\t-aruns\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\test\test\test.vcproj Line: 9 Column: 2 Error Message: The system cannot find the file specified. The file 'C:\Documents and Settings\t-aruns\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\test\test\test.vcproj' has failed to load.`

The relevant lines of the .vcproj file in question is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<VisualStudioProject
    ProjectType="Visual C++"
    Version="9.00"
    Name="test"
    ProjectGUID="{D60ADCAC-E0C0-470A-91EC-097BB293141A}"
    Keyword="AtlProj"
    TargetFrameworkVersion="196613"
    >
    <Platforms>
        <Platform
            Name="Win32"
        />
    </Platforms>
    <ToolFiles>
    </ToolFiles>
    <Configurations>
        <Configuration
            Name="Debug|Win32"
            OutputDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
            IntermediateDirectory="$(ConfigurationName)"
            ConfigurationType="2"
            UseOfATL="2"
            ATLMinimizesCRunTimeLibraryUsage="false"
            CharacterSet="1"
            >
            <Tool
                Name="VCPreBuildEventTool"
            />
...
```

Can anyone provide some guidance as to what the cause of this error message is?

Thank you.

~Arun

Answer (score 1):

Have you copied these files from another location that has security settings on the .vcproj file different than the user trying to upgrade?

Comment: No. I haven't. I should note that copying the project over to another VM fixes the problem, in that environment. After conversion, if I copy the files back, VS2010 cannot find any of the project files.